# Tic-Tac-Toe game weird behavior of the program

Tags: java

I'm working on a mini project in JAVA which is building an X/O game , I'm in the part where the program will figure out which is the next sign to show weither is it "X" or "O".
So I setup an eventlistener and wait for the user to click the button.
and I do the following for each button :

```
Button7.setBounds(50,180,80,30);
panel.add(Button7);
Button7.addActionListener(new ActionListener () {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    int countX = 0;
    int countO = 0;
    int difxo = 0;
    String xo = "";
    if (Button1.getText().equals("X"))
    {
        countX += 1;
    }
    else if (Button2.getText().equals("X"))
    {
        countX += 1;
    }
    else if (Button3.getText().equals("X"))
    {
        countX += 1;
    }
    else if (Button4.getText().equals("X"))
    {
        countX += 1;
    }
    else if (Button5.getText().equals("X"))
    {
        countX += 1;
    }
    else if (Button6.getText().equals("X"))
    {
        countX += 1;
    }
    else if (Button7.getText().equals("X"))
    {
        countX += 1;
    }
    else if (Button8.getText().equals("X"))
    {
        countX += 1;
    }
    else if (Button9.getText().equals("X"))
    {
        countX += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        countX += 0;
    }
    if (Button1.getText().equals("O"))
    {
        countO += 1;
    }
    else if (Button2.getText().equals("O"))
    {
        countO += 1;
    }
    else if (Button3.getText().equals("O"))
    {
        countO += 1;
    }
    else if (Button4.getText().equals("O"))
    {
        countO += 1;
    }
    else if (Button5.getText().equals("O"))
    {
        countO += 1;
    }
    else if (Button6.getText().equals("O"))
    {
        countO += 1;
    }
    else if (Button7.getText().equals("O"))
    {
        countO += 1;
    }
    else if (Button8.getText().equals("O"))
    {
        countO += 1;
    }
    else if (Button9.getText().equals("O"))
    {
        countO += 1;
    }
    difxo = countX - countO;
    if (difxo == 0)
    {
    xo = "X";
    }
    else if (difxo == 1)
    {
    xo = "O";
    }
    countX = 0;
    countO = 0;
    Button7.setText(xo);
    }
    });
```

So you can figure out that in X/O game (When the beginning sign is X) we can pretend which sign is after by doing a basic subsraction.
If the result of the sustraction is 1 : the sign in the button must be "O", and if the result is 0 the sign must be "X".
But in the program that I made, repeating the same for each button click event I get "X" "O" "X" "X" "X" instead of getting "X" "O" "X" "O" ... etc
I don't know why is that happening because each time I count "X"s and "O"s then do the substraction.
Thanks.

Comment: Oh, heavens. Whenever you have a bunch of repeated code with trivial changes (like your `ButtonX` conditionals), you're probably Doing It Wrong, and in this case your approach really doesn't make any sense. Is there a reason you can't just keep a variable (either a `bool` or an `enum`) saying whose turn it is instead of Rube-Goldberging it?

Comment: You should definitely read up on arrays. Seriously. Also, read up on how if/else works.

Answer (score 0):

Make a class field, say called "turn" that holds the state of the turn it should be. Best would be for it to be of an enum type, but it could hold a String. Then change the value whenever the turn changes.

For instance if your turn variable holds a String, and if your program has two String constants, X = "X" and Y = "Y", then you could use this code to swap turns:

```
turn = turn.equals(X) ? Y : X;
```

Other suggestions:

- Avoid absolute positioning. It's much easier to put the JButtons into a JPanel that uses a `GridLayout(3, 3)` and let the layout manager place them and help size them.
- Learn and follow Java naming conventions. Class, interface and enum names begin with an upper-case letter and variables and methods with a lower-case letter.
- A single ActionListener can work for all your game buttons.
- Make sure to check that the button hasn't already been selected before doing any action on its being pressed.
- As ppeterka 66 wisely suggests, the turn variable could be a simple boolean variable, say called isXTurn, and you could do your x-turn behavior by checking `if (isXTurn)` (and of course do the y-turn behavior in the else block) and then swap its value by doing `turn = !turn`.
- As suggested by others, use an array of JButtons to simplify your coding and debugging.

Regarding a single ActionListener, in pseudo-code, it could look like:

```
  @Override
  actionPerformed method
     First check if gameOver is true. If so, return;

     use e.getSource() to get the button pressed and put it 
        into a JButton local variable, button
     Use a for loop to iterate through the button array to 
        find out which button is pressed. Store in a variable(s)
     Set a String variable called text with the button's text.
     if the button's text has already been set (it's not empty) then return;
     set the button's text with the appropriate text based on the state of turn
     call checkForWin() method. Pass in the button's position in the button array.
     swap turns
   end of actionPerformed method
```

Comment: I think for this purpose, an old-fashioned boolean would do just as good (`isX` or `isO`...). There won't ever be more than 2 players I think. Though it could be interesting playing it in 3D with 3 players...

Comment: @ppeterka66: you are probably right, since it represents a binary value, and swapping it is as simple as `turn = !turn;` but for my simple way of thinking, I prefer to have turn represent either X or Y rather than true or false. It just seems more natural to me.

Comment: Well, on one hand, it might seem premature optimization (which I not intended the suggestion to be), but for me, it would be more readable having `if(isXTurn) {...` in the code than equals calls. The enum is a (very) close second to that.

Comment: @ppeterka66: again, I don't disagree, and will note this in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please clearify how can I use a single ActionListener to multiple buttons with a sample code .